# RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer issue - when running broadleaf admin on tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, broadleaf-commerce

I have build the whole app using maven and tried to deploy admin.war it on a standalone tomcat7, during the server start-up, it is showing some error : but still the server starts up, 
due to this , when i go to products->Inventory -> the **Available Quantity** field is missing. But the same field is available, when i am running through eclipse.

```
Dec 15, 2014 5:45:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\admin.war
[ WARN] 17:46:12 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'
[ WARN] 17:46:20 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a problem (likely that a LoadTimeWeaver is not registered). As a result, the Broadleaf Commerce ClassTransformer (org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.cop
y.DirectCopyClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.
[ WARN] 17:46:20 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a problem (likely that a LoadTimeWeaver is not registered). As a result, the Broadleaf Commerce ClassTransformer (org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.con
vert.EntityMarkerClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.
[ WARN] 17:46:20 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a problem (likely that a LoadTimeWeaver is not registered). As a result, the Broadleaf Commerce ClassTransformer (org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.cop
y.DirectCopyClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.
[ WARN] 17:46:31 AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [blSandBoxElements]; using defaults.
[ WARN] 17:47:14 DefaultFilterChainValidator - Possible error: Filters at position 12 and 13 are both instances of org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
[ WARN] 17:47:15 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'
Hibernate: select systemprop0_.BLC_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_ID as BLC1_167_, systemprop0_.FRIENDLY_GROUP as FRIENDLY2_167_, systemprop0_.FRIENDLY_NAME as FRIENDLY3_167_, systemprop0_.FRIENDLY_TAB as FRIENDLY4_167_, systemprop0_.PROPERTY_NAME as PROPERTY5_167_, systemprop0_.PROPERTY_TYPE as PROPERTY6_167_, sy
stemprop0_.PROPERTY_VALUE as PROPERTY7_167_ from BLC_SYSTEM_PROPERTY systemprop0_ where systemprop0_.PROPERTY_NAME=?
Dec 15, 2014 5:47:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Dec 15, 2014 5:47:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 15, 2014 5:47:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inventory was added in version 3.1.3 make sure you are using this version or newer version.

It was added using 
`org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.copy.DirectCopyClassTransformer`

Which adds the field at run time, but this creates the dependency on "Spring Instruments", which needs to be added as javaagent

So you can edit your /path/to/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh and add following

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -javaagent:/path/to/spring-jar/spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar"
```

Adjust Xmx and other tomcat setting and replace **/path/to/spring-jar/** with actual path.